# SVG dependency in Flutter

Tags: flutter

After adding flutter svg dependency in flutter i m getting below error while running app
Any help is much needed as i m new to flutter.

My requirement is to render SVG image in flutter, i m trying to do so getting above error

```
my pubspec.yaml file is as below:
name: login_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  flutter_svg: any

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons fonts is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the fonts family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the fonts. For
  # example:
  fonts:
      - family: Circular_Std_Bold
        fonts:
          - asset: fonts/circular_std_bold.ttf
            weight: 900
      - family: Soleil_Regular
        fonts:
          - asset: fonts/soleil_regular.ttf
            weight: 900


  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
  assets:
    - images/


Error as below:

../../../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.23.0+1/lib/svg.dart:325:5: Error: Type 'AssetBundle' not found.
    AssetBundle? bundle,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.23.0+1/lib/svg.dart:325:5: Error: 'AssetBundle' isn't a type.
    AssetBundle? bundle,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I m getting above error after adding flutter svg dependency,Please find pubspec.yaml file as above.

My requirement is to render SVG image in flutter, i m trying to do so getting above error

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to fix this? Having the same problem :\

Comment: yes i removed flutter_svg: any & added flutter_svg: ^0.22  version then i got build success later i reverted to flutter_svg: any then also build got success.Please try & let me know

Comment: Please up vote if u are also facing same issue

Comment: nice! I was able to fix it by updating my flutter version. glad you got it to work!